# The orbits of group representation

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

I will raise the question from an example. Let $G = \mathbb C^*$ be the multiplication group of nonzero complex numbers. Let $V$ be a $2$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb C$. There is a (reducible) representation of $\mathbb C^*$, $$\rho:\mathbb C^* \rightarrow GL(V),$$
sending $a \in \mathbb C^*$ to $\operatorname{diag}(a,a)\in GL(V)$. Then the orbits of this action of $\mathbb C^*$ on $V$ are $\{0\}$ and the lines without $0$. By omitting $\{0\}$, these orbits form $\mathbb P^1$ over $\mathbb C$.

Now consider arbitrary group $G$ and its representation over a $\mathbb C$-vector space $V$ (maybe infinite dimensional). When will the set of $G$-orbits of $V$ have a meaningful structure, like a $\mathbb C$-vector space, or a projective space?

Thanks.

Comment: What you seem to be interested in are Lie Groups. A Lie group is a group with topological structure, and a Lie group representation is defined to be a representation that preserves this structure.

Comment: Of course, finite groups are necessarily Lie Groups, but this doesn't seem to be in the spirit of what you want.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Thank you very much for the comments. I don't know much about Lie group representations. As is written on Wikipedia, a Lie group reprsentation is a smooth group homomorphism of the form $G \rightarrow GL(V)$, where $G$ is a Lie group and $V$ is a vector space over certain field. Then what can one say about the structure of the set of $G$-orbits in $V$? Thanks again.